# Row into Column in mysql without pivot and group concat

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I have a table like

```
ID    Student    Exam
----------------------  
1      Kavi      BE       
2      MGR       BA      
3      MGR1      BE
```

I am writing this data in excel format.The problem is that i need the exam field to be a column-wise like,

```
BE      BA 
-------------
Kavi    NULL 
NULL    MGR
MGR1    NULL
```

This should be done only with the query,because i can't modify excel class to make it to print column-wise data.

I have used group concat,but i need the exam details to be of a separate column and not in same column.I shouldnot use pivot since it is not supported by few versions of mysql.
Pls Help.

Note: This table may have as many as records,so pls provide solutions that can work dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT function so you will need to use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select
  max(case when exam = 'BE' then student end) BE,
  max(case when exam = 'BA' then student end) BA
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d97/2).

If you are going to have an unknown number of `exam` values then you will need to look at using a prepared statement with dynamic sql.  The code will be similar to:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when exam = ''',
      exam,
      ''' then student end) AS `',
      exam, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from yourtable;

SET @sql 
    = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
              from yourtable
              group by id;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d97/4).  Both versions give the result:

```
|     BE |     BA |
|   Kavi | (null) |
| (null) |    MGR |
|   MGR1 | (null) |
```

Comment: @bluefeet.I cannot use a static condition like exam = 'BE' or exam = 'BA', because there can be number of records added to this table.Can you provide these conditions as a dynamic one?

Comment: @user2743855 see my edit, you will have to use dynamic sql with  prepared statement to execute a sql string

Comment: While running the query in phpmyadmin,it gives null record even though i have the records as displayed.can you tell me the reason?is this supports myadmin?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO. No errors.I have attached screenshot for your view.
[link](http://postimg.org/image/wmailde79/)